# What are the mathematical and "real world" applications of "quadratic maps", a type of dynamical system?

Tags: recurrence-relations, generating-functions, dynamical-systems

If we suppose that we can get a [generating function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function) for any ["*quadratic map* (as in dynamical systems)"](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuadraticMap.html), what are the mathematical applications?  Also, what are the "real world" applications of this?  Would this, for instance, allow new computations that were previously unobtainable?

**MORE DETAILED EXPLANATION**

To show the problem, we start with an equation, which is our "quadratic map":
$$a_{n+1} = A(a_n)^2 + B(a_n) + C$$

Then we map it out into a generating function:
$$A(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + \dots + a_n x^n + \dots$$

So, for instance, 
$$a_1 = A(a_0)^2 + B(a_0) + C$$
$$a_2 = A\left(A(a_0)^2 + B(a_0) + C \right)^2 + B\left(A(a_0)^2 + B(a_0) + C \right) + C$$
$$= A^2(a_0)^4+2AB(a_0)^3+(2AC+B^2+A)(a_0)^2+(2BC + B)a_0+(C^2+2C)$$
$$\dots$$

Now we can suppose, for instance, that we know a very simple formula for $A(x)$.  In other words, $a_n$ may have a very complicated formula in terms of $a_0$, but the formula for $A(x)$ could be relatively simple in some cases.  How can the $A(x)$ simplification be used to advantage?

Comment: I don't see what's quadratic about your map, except for the deceptive notation in the first equation.

Comment: @Raskolnikov: I didn't intend to be deceptive.  I'm talking about "quadratic maps", which are a specific topic, and not just maps that are quadratic, or quadratic equations that are maps.  They are defined recursively in a quadratic fashion.  I've been trying to find more information about them.  There is some literature under "dyanamic systems", if that helps.

Comment: I don't see where you're getting a power series. $a_1$ is of degree 2, $a_2$ of degree 4, $a_3$ of degree 8 in $a_0$, etc., but that's a sequence of polynomials - where's the power series? And what do you have in mind when you ask for a generating function?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Sorry, changed the question to say I'm using a generating function.  There's no power series.  I have in mind a closed form in the strictest sense, I believe.  Just a function involving the variable $x$ and very basic/elementary arithmetic - not even summations or integrations.  The only other things present would be the exact expression for $a_0$.  I would like to know whether or not this could be useful.  I have asked a few related questions lately.

Comment: There is still a power series, you have written $A(x)=$ and what's on the right side of that equation is a power series. But I think what fooled me is your expansion of $a_2$, which made me misunderstand what you're doing. Anyway, what do you mean by "get" a generating function? You can certainly write down the generating function for any sequence whatsoever, quadratic or otherwise.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: What I'm trying to get at is that, for example, $\sin x = x - x^3/(3!) + x^5/(5!) - \dots$.  Here we could say that $a_n = \text{formula}$.  However, I'm wondering what we could do if we didn't know $a_n$, but knew that $\sin x$ represents the generating function for it.  In other words, what could we do with the $\sin x$?  We would, of course, know $a_{n+1}$ in relation to $a_n$, but the actual formula for $a_n$ in terms of $a_0$ could be quite lengthy.  I'm wondering what the $\sin x$ representation could be used for, assuming it's simpler.

Comment: So your question boils down to "if we have a simple, closed-form expression for the generating function of a sequence, what does it teach us about the sequence itself?", is that it?

Comment: For "real-world applications", note that the logistic map, a population model, is an example of a quadratic map. This map is notoriously complex (except for certain values of the parameter $r$), so any closed formula, generating function or otherwise, would be impressive. There is mention on the Mathworld page for the logistic map of a proof that no closed-form formula exists for general $r$.

Comment: @HughDenoncourt: I wonder anyways...I wonder if the possibility exists for other cases of the quadratic map.  I wonder what the proof says, concerning $r$ specifically.

Comment: @D.Thomine: Yes - at least that's part of it.  The general case for all recurrences is addressed elsewhere, in places such as Wilf's Generatingfunctionolgy.  However, I'm interested in "qaudratic maps" specifically, as described in the link that I give and in the description below.  I'm wondering what this specific "simple, closed-form expression" would allow us to do with "quadratic maps" in particular.